# Postgresql pgAdmin COPY issue

Tags: copy, pgadmin, psql

I have an sql script which creates a table and then populates it with a COPY FROM STDIN command.

The issue i am facing here is that the sql runs fine from the command line but pgAdmin gives me a syntax error.

Here is my code.

```
    COPY ui_geoip_city (id, country_code, region_code, city_name) FROM stdin;

    1   AD  07  Andorra La Vella

    2   AD  05  Anyѓs

    3   AD  04  Arinsal

    4   AD  02  Canillo

    5   AD  03  Encamp
.....
```

The Error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 156: 1 AD 07 Andorra La Vella
          ^
```

Comment: Which exact syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the data type of the column corresponds to the data type of the values you're inserting into the column, otherwise this error will appear.